# Is this a correct negation [part i]?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Original statement:

```
∀p. (Person(p) → 
     ∃c. (Cat(c) ∧ Loves(p, c) ∧
          ∀r. (Robot(r) → ¬Loves(c, r))
     )
)
```

Negation:

```
Ep. (Person(p) ∧
     ∀c. (Cat(c) ∧ Loves(p, c) ->
          Er. (Robot(r) ∧ Loves(c, r))
     )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  That is correct.

I would also add brackets around "$\operatorname{Cat}(c)\land\operatorname{Loves}(p, c)$", although that is just for clarity; it is not strictly necessary.

$$\neg~\forall p~.(\operatorname{Person}(p)\to\exists c~.(\operatorname{Cat}(c)\land\operatorname{Loves}(p,c)\land\forall r~.(\operatorname{Robot}(r)\to\neg\operatorname{Loves}(c,r))))\\[2ex]\Updownarrow\\[2ex]\exists p~.(\operatorname{Person}(p)\land\forall c~.((\operatorname{Cat}(c)\land\operatorname{Loves}(p,c))\to\exists r~.(\operatorname{Robot}(r)\land \operatorname{Loves}(c,r))))$$